# git is merging to the wrong branch

Tags: git, github

We just noticed at my work, that sometimes when I deploy to our test branch my merges go into the production branch instead, I rarely deploy to our production branch.

Even Git's auto message `"Merge branch 'feature/my-feature' into 'master'"` says that the branch was merged into test, but it shows up in the production branch.

Is this a bug?

The way I git is:

```
git status
git add .
git commit -m "MESSAGE HERE"
git checkout <testbranch>
git pull
git merge <localbranch>
press esc, :wq
git push origin test
```

If you look in the picture, you'll see what I mean. This branch was just a test branch, never to be in prod.

[image: Example Image]

Comment: I assure you that Git is merging precisely where you tell it to...

Comment: Then the picture?
That's not the only branch, there are lots of test files that aren't suppose to be in prod.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `git checkout test <branch>`?  Are you *only* trying to checkout the `test` branch?

Comment: You're waiting a year to ask this? Are you sure those are the commands you used in September of last year?

Comment: Yes, I'm relatively new to git, and I never try to do things outside of the norm.

Comment: The command `git checkout test branch` means *try to parse `test` as a commit or tree object; if that works, extract file `branch` from it; otherwise extract files `test` and `branch` from the current commit". It will not change your current branch.